My automated "click" Applescript has just stopped working
Right up until a week ago, my simple Applescript that had to simply click on a specific coordinate on screen just stopped working.
Here is the Applescript:
tell application "System Events"
click at {693, 619}
end tell

And I automate it's trigger at a specific time of day with the help of osascript (recommended for Applescripts) using the following plist file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mouseclick.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        <string>/Users/mugenvoid/Downloads/mouseclick.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>6</integer> <!-- Adjust the hour as needed -->
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>10</integer> <!-- Adjust the minute as needed -->
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

I've added this plist file to the LaunchDaemons folder of my core Library folder. This will ensure it's a global daemon, so it should have the highest chance of always triggering correctly. Beyond that, I've given all the relevant access and permissions (Accessibility, Automation, disk access etc) for this setup to work correctly.
To ensure the job is loaded correctly and functional, I use an application called Launchcontrol 2. Over there, it is always loaded in correctly and the status shows as OK.
Despite all these checks and balances, the script just doesn't click on the specific coordinate no more. It was always working perfectly fine up until a week ago and I haven't made any changes whatsoever to this whole setup.
The Launchcontrol 2 application has some launchd(8) logs of the job trigger event at the designated time that I would like to share. Perhaps it will help with the debugging. Here it is:
2024-10-22 06:10:03.808584 <Notice> internal event: WILL_SPAWN, code = 0
2024-10-22 06:10:03.808688 <Notice> service state: spawn scheduled
2024-10-22 06:10:03.808692 <Notice> service state: spawning
2024-10-22 06:10:03.808727 <Notice> launching: xpc event
2024-10-22 06:10:03.810543 <Notice> xpcproxy spawned with pid 28683
2024-10-22 06:10:03.810593 <Notice> internal event: SPAWNED, code = 0
2024-10-22 06:10:03.810599 <Notice> service state: xpcproxy
2024-10-22 06:10:03.810718 <Notice> internal event: SOURCE_ATTACH, code = 0
2024-10-22 06:10:03.827675 <Notice> service state: running
2024-10-22 06:10:03.827703 <Notice> internal event: INIT, code = 0
2024-10-22 06:10:03.827709 <Notice> job state = running
2024-10-22 06:10:03.827726 <Notice> Successfully spawned osascript[28683] because xpc event
2024-10-22 06:10:10.104597 <Notice> exited due to exit(0), ran for 6293ms
2024-10-22 06:10:10.104617 <Notice> service state: exited
2024-10-22 06:10:10.104630 <Notice> internal event: EXITED, code = 0
2024-10-22 06:10:10.104633 <Notice> job state = exited
2024-10-22 06:10:10.104665 <Notice> service inactive: com.mouseclick.plist
2024-10-22 06:10:10.104681 <Notice> service state: not running

To the best of my knowledge, I've checked everything possible from my end and am still faced with this roadblock. I'd really appreciate your support here!
Condensed view of what I've tried so far:

Under the Privacy & Security settings section, I enabled
Accessibility for osascript, launchcontrol and the script editors
I've used for the Applescript and the plist file. See image attached
below. Accessibility Settings
Under the Privacy & Security settings section, under Automation, the
requisite access has been given to Osascript and relevant
applications. See image attached below. Automation Settings
Ensured the job is loaded correctly with no errors and that it is
loaded in as a global daemon (by adding the plist file to the
LaunchDaemons foler in my core Library folder). See image attached
below. Launchcontrol 2 job view
Verified the script file and plist file and found no syntax errors
(code used for both has been shared above).
Ran the script file from the Script Editor itself to confirm if it's
working fine and got the following results. See image attached below.
Script run results


Please delete 'osascript' from the Accessibility list in the Privacy & Security settings, then add it back. Any change?

Yes, I did that. Gonna check if it works now.

The click is supposed on a Google Chrome window that I keep fully active and in the foreground to ensure nothing breaks.
And still the script fails to trigger properly and actually click...

Confirmed, the trick you asked me to do didn't work for me sadly.

Your script interacts with the user interface, so should not be run as a LaunchDaemon. See:
Designing Daemons and Services (developer.apple.com)
It shouldn't be run as a LaunchAgent either, but it may work if you move the job file to ~/Library/LaunchAgents. Be sure to unload the job from launchd and load it again in the new location. Ask if you don't know how to do that.
You also need to move the script file out of the Downloads folder, which is protected by TCC. Put it in ~/Library/Scripts or some such place.
A much better option would be to use the Calendar Alarm template in the Automator application to schedule the script. I think you have a previous question about that.

Thanks for the answer Linc Davis!
Originally, the plist file was actually in the ~/Library/LaunchAgents location that you mentioned. I only moved it out of there because as you know, the whole automation just stopped working.
The entire setup was working perfectly fine without any issues for months before suddenly ceasing to do so. The plist file was in the ~/Library/LaunchAgents location and the script file was in the Downloads location.
I'll implement your suggestion and see how it goes!

I do remember asking a question about this automation a few months back but don't remember discussing about using a "Calendar Alarm Template" from the Automator app to facilitate the same.
If your suggestion doesn't work, I'll reach out to you here to learn more about this alternative.

Here's what I did:
-- First unloaded the plist file through Launchcontrol and then deleted it from the previous LaunchDaemons folder.
-- Pasted it in the ~/Library/LaunchAgents location you mentioned and loaded it in using Launchcontrol.
-- Deleted the scripts from the Downloads folder and pasted them to the ~/Library/Scripts location you suggested.
Still the issue persists. And it's not like the script doesn't work.
When I "start" the job in Launchcontrol, I've confirmed it will perform a click at the UI element present in the specified coordinates.

But when the turn comes for the script to run automated at the specified time, nothing happens even if the Chrome window is active and at the forefront.
I've noticed that the job takes longer to finish executing (around 5000ms) as compared to when I just start and run it ad-hoc using Launchcontrol (around 250ms).
Any idea what might be happening here?
I'm also happy to learn about the "Calendar Alarm" template method you made mention of in your initial reply.

I really think you would do better to follow Apple guidelines and not use launchd for this purpose. See: https://macosxautomation.com/automator/calendar/index.html

No worries, I managed to get it resolved. Turn out that for some reason, the Google Chrome UI wasn't clickable by "System Events". When I opened the same webpage where I needed the click to happen on Safari, everything worked fine and dandy like before.
So it seems like the core issue here resided with Google Chrome. Some recent update must've made it's interface non-clickable by "System Events".
